# How to log to file inside brackground "watch" command?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I trying to set a watch task running in background and printing to a log file, but when i use the command in background, the files is not written. This is the command that i'm using:

```
watch -n1 'echo `date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%3N"` `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp` >> temp.log' &
```

then the terminal prints:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ watch -n1 'echo `date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%3N"` `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp` >> temp.log' &
[1] 29504
```

i try to kill the process:

```
kill 29504
```

so i want to see the log:

```
cat temp.log
```

But the file is empty ☹️. What happens?

Comment: You may be suffering from buffering. Try temporarily changing `...temp.log' &` into `... temp.log; yes "Some rubbish" | head -1000 >> temp.log' &` The idea is to add 1,000 lines of rubbish after every reading to force the buffer to be written to disk.

Comment: Could also be `opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp` is hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use `watch` for this? It's intended to be interactive. Use `while` `sleep` loop:

```
while true; do
  echo '`date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%3N"` `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp`';
  sleep 1;
done >> temp.log' &
```

Doesn't exactly simulate what you'd get from watch. You could do that more or less with this if you really wanted:

```
while true; do
  echo '`date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%3N"` `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp`';
  sleep 1;
done | head > temp.log' &
```

Comment: Reading I realized that "watch" does not work in background, so my solution is like the first example.